# .exe has stopped working code blocks cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, null, codeblocks, singly-linked-list

`Hello 
I just wrote this code in Code Blocks and after building and running , it says that the programm has stopped working. I can't find what I have done wrong. I don't know if the problem is related to my code or is something that has to do with the compiler I am using or something else.
Please help

Library.h:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Library
{
public:
    struct book
    {

        string tittle;
        int number;
        struct book* next;
    }* head, *tail, *ptr;

    Library();
    ~Library();
    book* searchName(book *, string);
    void addNode(book *);
    book *initNode(string s, int i);
    void displayNode(book *ptr) const;
    void displayList(book *ptr) const;
protected:
};

#endif
```

Library.cpp

```
#include "Library.h"

Library::Library() :
        head(NULL), tail(NULL)
{
}

Library::~Library()
{
    book *current, *temp;

    current = head;

    temp = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = current;
    }
}

Library::book * Library::searchName(Library::book* ptr, string name)
{
    while (name != ptr->tittle)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        if (ptr == NULL)
            break;
    }
    return ptr;
}

void Library::addNode(book *newNode)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    tail->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    tail = newNode;
}

Library::book *Library::initNode(string s, int i)
{
    book *ptr = new book;
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return static_cast<book *>(NULL);
    else
    {
        ptr->tittle = s;
        ptr->number = i;
        return ptr;
    }
}

void Library::displayNode(book *ptr) const
{

    cout << ptr->number << ": " << ptr->tittle << endl;
}

void Library::displayList(book *ptr) const
{
    if (!ptr)
        cout << "Nothing to display" << endl;
    while (ptr)
    {
        displayNode(ptr);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Library.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Library a;
    Library::book *ptrr;
    ptrr = a.initNode("s1", 1);
    a.addNode(ptrr);
    ptrr = a.initNode("s2", 2);
    a.addNode(ptrr);
    a.displayList(a.head);
}
```

Comment: Indent your code and then use a debugger....you'll find where the bug is.

Comment: `Library::book *Library::initNode(string s, int i)` should probably be a `book` constructor instead. `Library` shouldn't have to know how to construct a book. That's `book'`s job.

Comment: `void displayList(book *ptr) const` having to pass in a book to `displayList` seems a bit odd. `displayList` already knows its list. The current implementation would allow users to call `a.displayList(b.head);`, to get a list of `b` and that's just goofy. On the other hand `static void displayList(book *ptr)` would make sense.

Comment: displayNode is similar, but should be a member of `book`. No reason for `Library` to know how to print a `book`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the first `a.addNode(ptrr)` from `main` it does `tail->next = newNode;` (within `Library::addNode`), but, as `tail` is `NULL` (not assigned yet), it crashs....

Now, there could be other problems in the code, but this is most likely the first one that will make the program stop working...

Note that some stuff in your code could be simplified.

Like:

```
Library::book *Library::initNode(string s, int i)
{
    book *ptr = new book;
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return static_cast<book *>(NULL);
    else
    {
        ptr->tittle = s;
        ptr->number = i;
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

could simply be:

```
Library::book *Library::initNode(string s, int i)
{
    book *ptr = new book;
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        ptr->tittle = s;
        ptr->number = i;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

And:

```
void Library::addNode(book *newNode)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    tail->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    tail = newNode;
}
```

Should be:

```
void Library::addNode(book *newNode)
{
    if ( newNode != NULL ) // just in case
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newNode; // one is enough
        }
        if ( tail != NULL ) // to fix your crash
            tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

Also, see user4581301 comment, the destructor code does not even compile....

Comment: @user4581301: What does that mean?

Comment: `libri *current, *temp;` isn't the sort of thing that will compile. `book  *current, *temp;`, on the other hand...

Comment: @user4581301: True, but, actually, I did not work it around.....I simply did not try to compile the code at all...;-)

Comment: I meant book instead of libri ..the problem was that I had wrote head = newNode , instead of tail=newNode ..I works just fine now

Comment: @D.K you will also want to move the `tail->next = newNode; newNode->next = NULL; tail = newNode;` into an else. Without the else works, but it's a convoluted mess or stuff pointing to itself.